# Web Server & Emaill hosting in different server

Tags: azure, dns, hosting, azure-virtual-machine

I have hosted my website in Azure Server(VM) and also i have used to do a mail for another server.(but my mails are not working.)

> > Issue : Mails is not working.

for the illustration purpose i have paste the diagram and the DNS record i have put.

### Diagram

[image]

### DNS

Following DNS records i have put.. ( i connect azure server using 'A' record )

```
 Zone File Records
Name    TTL Class   Type    Record  Actions
mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   23.90.60.250     Edit    Delete
mail.mydomain.lk.   14400   IN  CNAME   mydomain.lk  Edit    Delete
www.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  CNAME   mydomain.lk  Edit    Delete
ftp.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
cpanel.mydomain.lk. 14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
webdisk.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
cpcalendars.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
cpcontacts.mydomain.lk. 14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
whm.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170  Edit    Delete
webmail.mydomain.lk.    14400   IN  A   207.174.200.170 Edit    Delete
```

Can anyone please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Could you describe the issue more, like how you verify it and what is the specific error?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT My Website & Mails are in different server.My mails is not working

Comment: I see these but how does mail server work on your side?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT Azure server used only for website hosting and it connects with "A" record. Email hosting provide in another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For receiving the emails you must put an MX record in the DNS pointing to the mail server you have setup as server 2.

```
mydomain.lk.   14400   IN  MX  webmail.mydomain.lk.
```